# Webview in flutter not working getting a platform error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Issue with webview in flutter getting an error

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
    PlatformException(error, Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/webview, null)
```

Trying to implement the webview
[image: getting the following error]

Comment: Are you figure a solution for this?

Answer (score 67):

I had the same problem.
But I did these steps, and it helped me:

#### 1) Add Internet permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

to the Android manifest:
`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` right above application tag.

#### 2) Add this key:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

in `ios/Runner/Info.plist`

#### 3) Add full url (with `http://www`)

#### 4) Call `flutter clean`, delete build folder.

Comment: calling the "flutter clean" is important in that case. thank you!

Comment: The `flutter clean` works well for me.

Comment: In my case, `https` works, and `http` gives an page-load error.

Comment: yup, "flutter clean" was enough, I didn't need to do those things in Android manifest and Info.plist

Answer (score 9):

I Faced this problem and solved it by changing the Android `minSdkVersion= 16` to  `minSdkVersion= 20` you can find it in :

> android > app > build.gradle

**why `minSdkVersion= 20` ?**

because I got the exception after using the plugin `youtube_player_flutter` and in the documentation of the plugin they stated that you should use android `minSdkVersion >= 20`, unfortunately flutter use by default `minSdkVersion= 16`, thats why I got `PlatformException`

*My Recommendation Dear reader is to look carefully at the plugins you are using and what version they are supporting on both Android and iOS*

Thats all I know ...

Comment: Getting same issue...Any Solution?

Comment: @NIKHATSHAIKH did you change the minSdkVersion ?

Comment: I have tried changing it but getting same issue :   defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutterapp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
Also have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1):

Some Webview support minimumSdk package 21.
Refresh the Project after changing minimumSdk

Answer (score 0):

if you have tried all before then this worked for me.

```
stop running
```

and

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score -1):

In **iOS**, you need to register plugins if they use native components.

To do this, you have to import FlutterPluginRegistrant in your project : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

```swift
import FlutterPluginRegistrant
```

After, you can use this line to register your plugins :

```swift
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: FlutterViewController)
```

⚠️ Be careful, you must to register your plugins once during the app lifecycle.

Answer (score -2):

the webview_flutter version in pubspec.lock is different from pubspec.yaml,you can change the version in pubspec.lock and it will solved